# Cypress folder not generating package v10.3.0

Tags: cypress

The cypress folder isn't generating, I've tried `npx cypress open`, `./node_modules/.bin/cypress open` and it's still not generating.
Also uninstalled and reinstalled cypress multiple times, clearing the cypress folder in %appdata% every time, but it still won't generate. Any ideas?

[image: Folder structure]

This is all that generates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have to first initialise the project using `npm init`.
2. Then install cypress using `npm install cypress`, as of the today the current version is 10.3.0, that should be installed.
3. Then You have to run the command `npx cypress open`, then you should see a window like this:

[image: test runner]

4. Click on **E2E Testing** and then cypress will give you a bunch of default configs that it's gonna add.

[image: config files]

5. Click on **Continue** button, you should get the Browser selection page.

[image: choose a browser]

6. Click on **Start E2E testing in Chrome** and you get Create your first spec page.

[image]

7. Click on **Scaffold Example Specs** and then **Okay, I got it**. This will add all the example specs to your e2e folder.

[image: test runner with specs]

8. After this you should see all the required files and cypress folder is created:

[image]

Comment: OMG you are a legend thank you so much!